# Convexity of the Pareto front: formal definition

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

Does anyone have a reference to a formal definition of what convexity of a Pareto front in multiobjective optimisation means? All literature I've seen uses the term without defining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Example 2.27 and Section 4.7.2 of [Boyd's Convex Optimization book](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf). Does it help?

Comment: Convexity of the set in equation (4.62) seems to do the trick:
$$\mathcal A = \{t\in \mathbb R^q\mid f(x)\leq t \text{ for some feasible } x\}$$